# External and internal multipole expansion for axisymmetric potential - the region of convergence

Tags: electromagnetism, potential, multipole-expansion

Say, we have a system of electrodes exhibiting symmetry around a certain axis. We know the explicit expression for the potential on the axis $\phi (z)$. We want to find the potential for any point in space with an arbitrary accuracy.

There is a great way to achieve this, which I found in the book 'Static and Dynamic Electricity' by William R. Smythe (chapter 5, paragraph 17). The method is as follows: Take the function $\phi(z)$ and expand it into power series $C_n z^n$ ($n \in \mathbb{Z}$), which converges for every $z \in (a,b)$. Then the potential in spherical coordinates in the region $r \in (a,b)$ can be expressed by the same power series with $z$ replaced by $r$ and every term $C_n r^n$ multiplied by a Legendre polynomial $P_n(\cos \theta)$.

What I don't understand is how to handle different intervals of convergense for 
$\phi (z)$. Say, we have

$$
\phi (z) = \phi_1 (z) + \phi_2 (z) + \phi_3 (z)
$$

We can expand every summand in Taylor series around $z=0$ and/or around $z \rightarrow \infty$, or around any other point. But each expansion converges on its own particular interval. In the simplest case I encountered we have some $z=b_i$ with the condition that:

$$
\phi_i (z)=\begin{cases} \sum_{0}^\infty A_n z^n & z \in (0,b_i)\\ z\sum_{-\infty}^0 B_n z^n & z \in (b_i,\infty)\end{cases} 
$$

With both infinite series converging to a finite sum.

As I understand the general solution for Laplace's equation in axisymmetric case has the form

$$
\phi_i (r,\theta)=\sum_{0}^\infty \left( A_n r^n+B_n \frac{1}{r^{n+1}} \right) P_n (\cos \theta)
$$

---

Finally, my question is this: if all $\phi_i (z)$ have different $b_i$ then can I still obtain the potential at every point in space (except maybe $r=b_i$) by expanding each $\phi_i (z)$ into the correct power series in its own interval of convergence? I will then have a number of piecewise functions $\phi_i (r, \theta)$ which I can add together to get the final expression for the potential.

I thought I could, but in [this](http://www.jpier.org/PIERB/pier.php?paper=11042106) paper it seems that the author only writes the potential for $r<b_{min},~r>b_{max}$, leaving the region of space containing the 'electrodes' unsolved.

Comment: In general, a break at $z=b_i$ does not happen just by itself, and there's typically a physical reason for it. (That doesn't mean that there needs to be something at $z=b_i$ itself, though, as e.g. the Taylor series of $1/(1+z^2)$ stops at $z=1$ even though the function is perfectly regular there.) That said, the setup is not quite clear. Is this in vacuum, or in the presence of charges? Is there a specific reason to decompose $\phi$ as a superposition?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty, this is in vacuum, and the superposition is caused by the presence of three different charged surfaces (as a an approximation of three real electrodes of different shapes)

Comment: Is the presence of (different) finite convergence radii an actual problem you're faced with? If so, providing a specific example would be very helpful, and would go a long way towards making this question answerable.